# How to get thread Trace in python GIL

Tags: python-3.x, gil

In python how to get  trace of thread interaction in GIL.

```
t2 100 5351 ENTRY
t2 100 5351 ACQUIRE
t2 100 5352 RELEASE
```

I have gone through the [GIL PDF](https://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf) there i can see that traces of thread entry, acquire, release events. I want to know how we can get those traces.